# How to remove howdy dropdown menu content

Tags: functions, themes, wp-admin, templates

[image]

I would like to know how I can remove content inside .ab-sub-wrapper but keep Log Out and Edit My Profile links? Just want to keep thing nice and tidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wordpress [nodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_nodes) to customize profile menu.

**Add this in `functions.php`**

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_my_account', 999 );
function remove_my_account( $wp_admin_bar ) {
   $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'my-account' );
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_logout', 999 );
function add_logout( $wp_admin_bar ) {
   $args = array(
      'id'     => 'logout',           // id of the existing child node (New > Post)
      'title'  => 'Logout',           // alter the title of existing node
      'parent' => 'top-secondary',    // set parent
  );
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided code. It is what I am after. Nice and simple exit button.